# soap ui returns html page not soap fault

Tags: soapui

I have a soap ui test case that fires off a soap request in one test step and then initiates a mock in the second. The problem is that the target service called in step 1 responds too quickly, ie. before the mock is stood up by soap ui's Jetty. So that target service now receives and HTML page instead of a soap message, which I can't handle. Any way to get soap ui to respond with a soap fault instead of an HTML page?

Comment: Execution in soapUI is sequential and the second step will be executed only when the first one is successful, so putting the mock service code in the second step is the wrong way to do this. The mock service can be started up in the setup script of the test suite or just manually start the mock service before starting execution.

Comment: This is good advice, what I ended up doing was:

1. Create a stand-alone mock service for the operation on the required wsdl and remote the mock step from the my test case

2. In the setup function of the test case, start the mock service

3. In the test case, create a listener loop using a wait test step followed by a script step that checks a test case property (eg. messageReceived, intialised to false) each time it is invoked

4. in the afterMessageReceived function of the mock service, navigate back to the test case and set 'messageReceived' to 'true'

This works a treat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execution in soapUI is sequential and the second step will be executed only when the first one is successful, so putting the mock service code in the second step is the wrong way to do this. The mock service can be started up in the setup script of the test suite or just manually start the mock service before starting execution.